# Make Form Fields Optional with JavaScript Validation

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I have JavaScript form validation functions like so:

```
function validate_name(field) 
{
    if (field == "") return "Please enter the name.\n";
    return "";
}

function validate_specialty(field) 
{
    if (field == "") return "Please enter the specialty.\n";
    return "";
}

function validate_location(field) 
{
    if (field == "") return "Don't forget the location.\n";
    return "";
}
```

where the function that is called from the form's `onSubmit` is:

```
function validate_fields(form)
{
    fail  = validate_name(form.name.value);
    fail += validate_specialty(form.specialty.value);
    fail += validate_location(form.location.value);

    if (fail == "")     
        return true;
    else 
    { 
        alert(fail); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works fine but I have decided that I don't want all three to necessarily be required.  It would be great if I could make these three optional, such that if any one of these fields is filled in, it would validate true, but if all three fields are empty, I could throw an alert and validate false.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by capturing the results separately, and testing with an OR grouping.

```
function validate_fields(form)
{
    fail1 = validate_name(form.name.value);
    fail2 = validate_specialty(form.specialty.value);
    fail3 = validate_location(form.location.value);

    if (fail1 == "" || fail2 == "" || fail3 == "")     
        return true;
    else 
    { 
        alert(fail1 + fail2 + fail3); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This similar to something I tried, but I used an alert string instead. It didn't work but I think I will try it just as you wrote it to see if I did something wrong.  Thanks or the tip.

Comment: This worked liked a charm.  The method I was using left out the `alert(fail1 + fail2 + fail3)` and had `alert("Failed")` which I thought would have worked (although now looking at it, seems like a silly way to do it), but it wasn't thought out - thanks again!