# Strange GET Data Causing 404 Error - JavaScript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, get, http-status-code-404

I want to refer to this post, because it might relate:

[Make Form Fields Optional with JavaScript Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848116/make-form-fields-optional-with-javascript-validation)

I have a form with three optional fields, as described above.  If I click the submit button, the JavaScript alerts come up, but the last one is a URL instead of the string I specify in the JavaScript function (the one that isn't an alert strong but an URL).

After a second, the page tries to go to an invalid URL:

`localhost.../index.php/Don%27t%20forget%20the%20location.`

As it turns out the `Don%27t%20forget%20the%20location.` is the alert string I have in the JavaScript function.

I thought that I might have some weird code that I accidentally pasted somewhere causing this but I scoured my files and found nothing out of the ordinary that would cause this.  Not sure if this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I have JavaScript form validation functions like so:

```
function validate_name(field) 
{
    if (field == "") return "Please enter the name.\n";
    return "";
}

function validate_specialty(field) 
{
    if (field == "") return "Please enter the specialty.\n";
    return "";
}

function validate_location(field) 
{
    if (field == "") return "Don't forget the location.\n";
    return "";
}
```

where the function that is called from the form's `onSubmit` is:

```
function validate_form(form)
{
    name  = validate_name(form.name.value);
    specialty = validate_specialty(form.specialty.value);
    location = validate_location(form.location.value);

    if (name == "" || specialty == "" || location == "")
    {
        return true;
    }

    else 
    { 
        alert("You must enter at least one field:\n\n" + name + specialty + location);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  It should be there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the variable `location` refers to `window.location` in that case (the url). So if you change your variable name, that should work:

```
userLocation = validate_location(form.location.value);
```

and

```
alert("You must enter at least one field:\n\n" + name + specialty + userLocation);
```

Comment: Damn, good catch.  That's what being a beginner will get you.  I had no idea.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I've been programming javascript for years and I had no idea either before trying it myself :)